# Swift: How to access array of dictionaries in an array of dictionary?

Tags: swift

```
The json is something like this:

{
 "Next": "0",
 "ErrorCode": "",
 "Data": [{
   "Item 1": "3",
   "Item 2": "2",
   "Item 3": "2",
    }]
}
```

How to access the "Data" from array of dictionary and display in table view.

"Item 1" should be displayed in a label
"3" should also be displayed in a label

Comment: What have you tried, what is the issue with _your_ code?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the JSON is coming as a response from API call. You can do the following.

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
    {
         if let data = json["Data"] as? [[String:Any]] {
             for item in data {
                let firstItem = item["Item 1"] as! String.
                print(firstItem)
        }
   }
    } else {
        print("bad json")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

I believe you can access it via keypath as well something like

```
dictionaryContainingJSON[keyPath: "Data.item 1"]
```